# How to Pass data from UIPickerView to previous ViewController with NavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I am trying to make a settings screen where at ViewController A that has MapView and ViewController A has functions to have these pins put on the map.

I am trying to read UIPickerView data in ViewController B and have it sent to the ViewController  A with a button click. In ViewController A another function called determineCity() would assess the data it received.

```
func determineCity(){
    switch incomingData {
    case "0":
        IzmirSelected()
        break
    case "1":
        print("San Francisco")
    default:
        print("Other")
    }
```

```
    @IBAction func setCityButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    if selectedData != "-1" {
    self.delegate?.SendDataToViewController(info: selectedData)
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    }
```

I have tried the delegate method where it does not send the data to ViewController A. The code on the ViewController A never changes.

What can I try to do to send this data to ViewController A. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the delegate to not work this means it's either nil

```
self.delegate?.SendDataToViewController(info: selectedData)
```

or assigned to another instance that's not the presented one , another way is to do

```
let all = self.navigationController!.viewControllers 
let vcB = all[all.count - 2] as! VCBName
vcB.callMethodHere()
```

Comment: It still doesnt seem to write the selectedData at ViewControllerB to incomingData at ViewController A. But your method successfully executes to function.